# Can we use multiple terms condition in elasticsearch filters

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-plugin

Is it possible to use multiple terms condition for specific fields in bool filter?

```
query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "terms": {
                        "events": [
                           "abc",
                           "def",
                           "ghi",
                           "jkl"
                        ]
                     },
                     "terms" : {
                        "users" : [
                          "user_1",
                          "user_2",
                          "user_3"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

First terms filter is working fine, but i am not able to use second terms, Please correct if i am doing anything wrong with the above query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there, you forgot one brace. Here's correct query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "events": [
                  "abc",
                  "def",
                  "ghi",
                  "jkl"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "users": [
                  "user_1",
                  "user_2",
                  "user_3"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will evaluate both conditions:

1. Your event must be one of abc/def/ghi/jkl
2. User must be either user_1/user_2/user_3

Basicly each terms query/filter needs to be wrapped up in its' own braces and they need to be siblings.